# How to solve this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 tables: `item`, `grp` and `grp_rel`.

`item` table:

```
item_id     title
```

`grp` table:

```
grp_id      title
```

`grp_rel` table:

```
grp_id      item_id
```

Data in table (`item` table): item title is `varchar(255), not unique`

```
1       item-a
2       item-b
3       title-c
4       item-d
5       title-c
6       value-e
7       value-e
```

Data in table (`grp` table): `grp title` is `varchar(255), not unique`.

```
1   title
2   value
```

Data in table (`grp_rel` table):

```
1   3
1   5
2   6
2   7
```

Expected sql result is (order by item title):

```
item_id     grp_id  title       grp_title
1           NULL    item-a      NULL
2           NULL    item-b      NULL
3           1       title-c     title
4           NULL    item-d      NULL
6           2       value-e     value
```

Comment: Please provide details about what you've done so far to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
SELECT MIN(it.item_id) as item_id,MIN(gr.grp_id) as grp_id,it.title,gr.title
FROM item it 
left join  grp_rel gl on it.item_id=gl.item_id 
left join grp gr on gl.grp_id=gr.grp_id
GROUP BY it.title,gr.title
ORDER BY it.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `left join` will do the job for you.

```
SELECT 
      I.item_id, 
      G.grp_id, 
      I.title, 
      G.title
FROM 
      item I
LEFT JOIN 
      grp_rel GR
      ON GR.item_id = I.item_id
LEFT JOIN 
      grp G
      ON G.grp_id = GR.grp_id
ORDER BY 
      I.title
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d64ed/9)